# HTML Parsing and flutter

Tags: html, firebase, parsing, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have been working on getting a way for my Joomla sites to communicate with my flutter mobile apps.  One of my partners was able to write a component for this process and automatically after each save, update firebase.

here is the question that I am asking.  I am able to get the code into my flutter app from firebase, parse out the HTML as it appears in the console of Android Studio, but it wont print to the Text Widget.

I tried adding a variable after the parse, but to no avail.  Let me know if you have any suggestions or solutions.  The text "introtext"from firebase is printing in the console.

```
  body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('com_content.article').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data..Please Wait..');
      get(snapshot.data.documents[0]['title'].toString());
      get(snapshot.data.documents[0]['introtext'].toString());
      var title = parse('title');
      var introtext = parse('introtext');
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Text: ${this.title}'),
            Text('Text: ${this.introtext}'),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  ) ,
);
```

}
}
...

Answer (score 0):

Well it only took about 4 hours, but i got it figured out.

The advantage to this is it helps MYSQL and the Joomla CMS functions to talk to firebase.  Everytime an article is saved from either the front end or backend of joomla, it is autoupdated in firebase.

A heck of alot easier than using an automation service like zapier or writing a ton of REST API code.

This does the following

- Joomla send MYSQL data to firebase
- firebase sees the incoming and auto creates a new document in the
  collection
- Flutter app then calls firebase using StreamBuilder
- Using the plugin flutter_html and the Html() inject the snapshot that
  needs to be parsed
- Run app and displays without markup

See below for the code

...

```
body: StreamBuilder(         Stream:Firestore.instance.collection('com_content.article').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if(!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data..Please Wait..');

      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Html(
          data: snapshot.data.documents[0]['introtext'].toString(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          onLinkTap: (url) {
            print("Opening $url...");
          },
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
```

...